# Compare text in react-native

Tags: react-native

How can you compare two text objects in React Native.

Sorry if the question is too triv. but after an hour of probing all possibilities I can't find the correct one.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = { text: ''}
}

render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputText}
      onChangeText={this.onChangeDo(this)}
    />
  </View>
 );
}

  onChangeDo(event){
  (text) => this.setState( {text} )
  if(text equals 'string'){
  ...
 }
 else{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of two items you might be comparing, and what kind of comparison you are doing? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you could check the text and then set the state of a variable in the function that is called onChangeText. [Here](https://rnplay.org/apps/pWvSsg) is an example, and I've pasted the code below as well.

https://rnplay.org/apps/pWvSsg

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Component
} = React;

class SampleApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { text: ''}
  }

  onChangeDo(text) {
    this.setState({ text })
    if (text === 'Hello') {
        return this.setState({ hello: true })
    }
    this.setState({ hello: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Type Hello"
          style={styles.inputText}
          onChangeText={ (text) => this.onChangeDo(text) }
            />
        { this.state.hello && <Text style={ styles.hello }>Hello World</Text> }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 60
  },
  inputText: {
    height:60,
    backgroundColor: '#ededed'
  },
  hello: {
    fontSize:22
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

For large Strings use this approach:

```
let questions="Hello how are you doing.........................are you fine?............................Whats your full name?.............";

let compareQuestions="Hello how are you doing.........................are you fine?............................Whats your full name?.............";

let comp= Array.from(questions).map((x) => {
        return typeof x === 'string' ? x : '';
      }).join('')==Array.from(compareQuestions).map((x) => {
        return typeof x === 'string' ? x : '';
      }).join('')
console.log("compare============",comp)
```